# Internalization on html page

Tags: mysql, html, frameworks, internationalization

I have a question, how would I do the following?

- I want to display a dropdown (html) with a list of language (english, french, etc.), ISO 639-1 codes. I want to display the language based on the native language (e.g., on the combo box, the "french" must say "francais" for the french speaking people to understand).

How I would do it? i,e. This is how I did it in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LANGUAGE
(
     LANGUAGE_CODE              VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL    --ISO 3 digit digit code
     ,LANGUAGE_NAME_ENGLISH     TEXT NOT NULL
     ,LANGUAGE_NAME_NATIVE      TEXT NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

The only problem, I cannot populate "LANGUAGE_NAME_NATIVE" since 1) I cannot get all native languages, and 2) I don't have languages in UTF8 format.

Is there any better way to do this?

Basically, what I'm accenuating is this: Should I have a language table for all the language list of all respective language; should I have i18n configuration files (properties file) for all languages list in their respective language or should I use a language translator?

**PS** I'm using MVC like Spring MVC and Struts.

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding the *actual* question/problem. Aren't you to the point just asking how to get translations for the language names you already have in English? The answer would then be: look for a translator or peek around in Wikipedia or Google Translate, but that's after all *too* straightforward and non-programming-related so that I thought I misinterpreted the actual question/problem.

Comment: @BalusC, Basically I have the list of languages from the ISO 639-1 list. The problem is not to display all the languages in english but each language in their respective locale. Do I have to do it in Database level or is there a translation tool that does that? Sorry if my question looks greek-ish! LOL

Comment: Are you jokings about problem 2) ? For the first one you can get the data from Unicode CLDR.

Comment: @Sorini, Nope, I wanted each language names in their native language (hence UTF8). What's CLDR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing in DB level is fine. The only alternative is to store it in same place as the translations. If those are filebased, it would be too expensive to open/load every file to gather the available languages.

Left behind your question how to get the translations: no tool comes to mind. How are you actually doing the "normal" translations? Using a human translator? Let him/her do the job translating the language name and insert it in the DB yourself. Alternatively, parse [this](http://www.omniglot.com/language/names.htm) or [this](http://www.geonames.de/languages.html).

Comment: My initial idea is to use Google translator on the fly....but what if Google server crash? I'm looking at efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: That's an extremely bad idea. It's not only expensive, but it also makes no sense. Languages doesn't change daily. I.e. it's static information. Isn't this question more an evidence of laziness? :) You would already almost be finished by routinely gathering and inserting the data in DB in the time you spent waiting for answers on this question...

Comment: @BalusC, now how would I store these native languges in database seeing I can't copy paste these languages to a SQL statement?

Comment: Insert it yourself. There's no magic. That's why they hired you. Hint: you can create a multi-insert statement by writing SQL like so `INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (val1a, val2a), (val1b, val2b), (val1c, val2c)`.

Comment: LOL @BalusC, it's not that....it's that many editors cannot support locales, e.g. language "dinka" (Thuɔŋjäŋ). How would I store value in bracket then?

Comment: I would say that you've to look for a better editor which supports UTF-8. Even PhpMyAdmin accepts it perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

many frameworks allow you to do i18n configuration via properties files.  You would have a properties file for each supported language.  All properties files would have the same keys but different values, and you would use the keys in your presentation layer.  You will have to look at the documentation for whatever technologies you are using...

edit -- here is a link i found for struts... http://www.allapplabs.com/struts/struts_internationalization.htm

Comment: That's cool, but I have to make it MVC independent (if you know what I mean).

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by 'MVC Independent' -- your problem is that users are going to select their language, and then you are going to display your content in whatever language they select, right?  If that is your problem, then using the i18n solution of Spring/Struts/Whatever you are using seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I agree, my thing is this, I have a language list (from ISO 639-1) that's fully in English so a Taiwanese person won't understand that "Taiwanese" is his language. I want to display all the languages in their respective language. How would I do this "translation" thing? keep it in db or use a translation tool or keep a list in a i18n configuration file?

Comment: aaaaahhh i see now.  Hmm I don't know.  Storing in the DB seems like a  good idea then, but I don't know how to solve the specific issue you mentioned...sorry